# Android Studio Windows: Debugger process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)

Tags: android, debugging, native

I have both native code and Java in my app so I need to be able to debug both Java and native code.

After upgrading to Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2, I can no longer debug my app with native debugging enabled. If the 'Debug type:' is set to `Java Only`, I can run in debug mode and trace through Java code but cannot trace into native functions. If 'Debug type:' is set to `Detect Automatically`, `Native Only` or `Dual (Java+Native)` the debugger fails to start.

I never had trouble debugging native code before. When I try to start in debug mode I get the following error:

`Debugger process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135). A library required by the native debugger might be missing on your system.`

How do I find out what library is missing? I upgraded everything that Android Studio said had updates.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Run->Edit Configurations" then select the "Debugger" menu item and check to see if "Debug type" was set to "Detect Automatically". If so, try setting it to "Java Only", apply that and see if the debugger now works. That's what fixed it for me.

Comment: This is not what I asked. I can debug if I select Java Only but I need native debugging to debug native code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, Android-studio was/is not able to handle Native-code debugging, but `android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()` + Attatch may work for Android-studio 4.x